# No residency for Australian visa application

Tags: australia, residency, working-holiday

I am wanting to apply for an Australian working holiday visa and one of the questions is my usual residence and asks for an address. 
Here's the thing. I don't have a *usual* country or residence. I have lived the past 5 years in Australia on a student visa so would think that as my country of residence (but I can't put AU for a holiday visa in AU). I haven't been in my country of passport in over 6 years and only lived there as a baby. I am currently in South Korea on a tourist visa where my parents have recently temporarily immigrated, but we are still in a hotel, so I can't put the hotel address either. 
So I technically have no country of residence. What do it put in the application?

Comment: 5 years. That's where you live usually. Totally fine to put that. You can also put a note at the end explaining the above.

Comment: @MarkMayo that could potentially be very bad advice, if the people reviewing the visa want to see that the applicant will leave Australia after the term of the "working holiday" ends.

Comment: @mlc Australia might want to see that the OP leaves Australia after the student visa too.

Comment: @mlc all you need is an exit ticket. It's a working holiday visa, have plenty of friends who have done them in Aus and didn't need proof of a job to return to or anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is meant by “Country of residence” in Australian Visa Application form?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55934/what-is-meant-by-country-of-residence-in-australian-visa-application-form?rq=1)